# WooCommerce: Step-by-step varations choices of product

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress site with WooCommerce installed. It's for a client thwa wants to sell products that has a lot of variations, that the customer has to choose between step-by-step.

I'm thinking about if you could try to add some custom PHP code that does the trick, or maybe it is possible to use JavaScript/jQuery to create a side-to-side scrollable page from HTML thats otherwise scrollable top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Variable products allow you to create a single product entry for multiple styles. This allows you to manage the product sales more easily. An example of a variable product is a t-shirt with a single design that comes in multiple colors and sizes.

Visit this link [varient](http://kb.oboxsites.com/knowledgebase/woocommerce-how-to-setup-products-with-multiple-optionsvariations/)

Comment: Thank you for your help! But it is the actual step-by-step kind of wizard my client needs. Like in the first step you chose color, press next to chose size, next again for input of label and so on. Not everything just simply on the page in a list.

Comment: The is no ready to use plugin as per my knowledge you have to write the logic for it or plugin for the same.Thanks

Comment: Yeah I thought so. But Then I wonder what would be the most suitable/efficient way of doing so? Could you use JS to move a page horizontally?